# MySQL Update problem

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

My mysql query is not updating my database correctly can some one help me fix this problem I think it has something to do with the JOIN.

Here is my mysql query.

```
"UPDATE users 
 SET users.last_login = NOW() 
 FROM users JOIN info ON info.user_id = users.user_id 
 WHERE (info.email = '" . $e . "' OR users.username = '" . $e . "') 
 AND users.password = '" . $sha512 . "' 
 AND users.active IS NULL"
```

Here is the working query before I used the JOIN.

```
"UPDATE users SET last_login = NOW() WHERE (email = '" . $e . "' OR username = '" . $e . "') AND password = '" . $sha512 . "' AND active IS NULL"
```

Comment: Under *no* circumstances reveal 1. what exactly goes wrong; 2. What the final, generated SQL statement looks  like; and 3. What result you expect. Otherwise, we would miss all the fun of guessing!

Comment: @Pekka my last login does not update, I expect the last_login to update the time when logged in.

Comment: @needHELP you need to show the final query with the actual values in it (instead of the PHP variables)

Comment: @Pekka the php variable are not the problem.

Comment: @needHelp Does it work when you `SELECT` a record this way? Do you get results?

Comment: yes it works when I check a record it logs me in but it just wont update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query syntax is wrong. The syntax for cross-table update in MySQL is somewhat
 different than T-SQL. It should be as below.

```
 UPDATE users JOIN info ON info.user_id = users.user_id
 SET users.last_login = NOW()   
 WHERE (info.email = '" . $e . "' OR users.username = '" . $e . "') 
 AND users.password = '" . $sha512 . "' 
 AND users.active IS NULL
```

Check the below link -

http://blog.ookamikun.com/2008/03/mysql-update-with-join.html

Comment: forgive my ignorance what is T-SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the tables or the generated SQL, I am just guessing here, as **Peeka** pointed out.

My guess is that you have data in your tables that allow the `(email = '" . $e . "' OR username = '" . $e . "')` to work. However, this is pretty open - update any record that has an email OR a username. When you add the `JOIN` it's more strict -  update *the* record that has this email OR username.

Check you second update, I bet it's not updating the record you think it is. If it is, I'd say your foreign keys are messed up and you don't have matching data in users and info. Either of these would demonstrate the `JOIN` is failing.

If that doesn't help - post the resulting SQL and your schema.